# Visio - Glue / Snap to shape without connection points

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

Is there a way to simply connect 2 shapes with a dynamic line in Visio 2013 so that the line will follow the shape geometry?

I'm aware of the connection points tools, but I'm looking for a way to simply connect 2 shapes with the shortest line (straight or right-angle line).

I'm pretty sure that there were a feature like this in Visio 2010, but I can't find it anymore (You used to be able to connect to the shape, not to the connection point, then the line would follow the geometry of the shape. Usually squares)

I've been looking through other questions in superuser but haven't found anythign that actually answers the question

Answer (score 3):

Glue the connector to the centre of the shape. Then when shapes move the connector will appear to follow the geometry even though it is actually glued to the shape's centre.
You might need to check Visio Snap and Glue settings (menu **View** -> **Visual Aids**).

Comment: for outgoing connections this is working pretty good, but if i want ingoing connections with an arrow shape, this doesn't place the arrow in a way that it conencts to the geometry border...